# Reshaping data in R using column names

Tags: r

I have the following data which I wish to reshape into the desired outputs (desired output 1 and 2) in R, whereby I need to parse variable names into the added column based on original values of multiple columns in input data.

Attached is the screenshot.

Appreciate for any assistance.

[image: data from input to desired outputs]

Comment: Try `cbidn(df1[1], OUTPUT=apply(df1[-1], function(x) toString(x[x!=0])))`

Comment: @akrun , I'm not sure what you intended here.  I can't get your code to work.  It isn't clear to me if you meant `lapply` or `apply` (if `apply` you're missing the `MARGIN` argument), and I can't get the desired output with any obvious permutation of those options. (also, you misspelled `cbind`)

Comment: I have some typos there and you are right.  I meant `cbind(DF[1], OUTPUT=apply(DF[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) toString(names(x)[x!=0])))`

Comment: I see it now.  I think you meant `cbind(DF[1], OUTPUT=apply(X = DF[-1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x!=0])))` (you need the `names(x)` or you get `1, 1` in return instead of `B, D`).....and you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,
                 A = c(0, 1, 1),
                 B = c(1, 0, 0),
                 C = c(0, 0, 0),
                 D = c(1, 0, 1),
                 E = c(0, 1, 0))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

out1 <- 
  gather(DF, letter, bit, A:E) %>%
  filter(bit == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID, letter)

out2 <- 
  out1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(output = paste0(letter, collapse = ","))
```